# CookieHelper Error, creating cookie again and again

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Created this simple class to create cookie. But creating cookie again and again.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CookieHelper
/// </summary>
public class CookieHelper
{
    private Page _page = null;
    public bool success { get; private set; }

    public bool CreateSuccess { get; private set; }
    protected bool SaveSuccess { get; private set; }
    protected bool DeleteSuccess { get; private set; }

    public bool IsExisting { get;private set; }
    public string cookieName { get; set; }

    public CookieHelper(Page page)
    {
        _page = page;
        CreateSuccess = SaveSuccess = IsExisting = DeleteSuccess = false;
    }

    public bool Exist(string cookieName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cookieName can't be null");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (_page.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
                {
                    IsExisting = false;
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsExisting = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("cookieName given to Exist check function is invalid or not string");
            }
        }
    }

    public void CreateCookie(string cookieName, int expiryTimeInMinutes=1, bool secure = true)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cookieName can't be null");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (Exist(cookieName))
                {
                    IsExisting = true;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpCookie cookie=new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiryTimeInMinutes);
                    cookie.Secure = secure;
                    CreateSuccess = true;
                    IsExisting = true;
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("CookieName type mismatch.  The parameter is of type '{0}', was expecting '{1}'.",
                    cookieName.GetType(), "a".GetType()));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool SaveInCookie(string cookieName, string valueKey, string valueToBeStored, int expiryTimeInMinutes, bool secure = true)
    {
        SaveSuccess = false;
        if (typeof(string) != cookieName.GetType() || typeof(string) != valueKey.GetType() || typeof(string) != valueToBeStored.GetType() || typeof(bool) != secure.GetType() || typeof(int) != expiryTimeInMinutes.GetType())
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter type mismatch");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = null;
                if (_page.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
                {
                    cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                    CreateSuccess = true;
                    IsExisting = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cookie = _page.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
                    IsExisting = true;
                    CreateSuccess = false;
                }

                cookie.Values.Add(valueKey, valueToBeStored);
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiryTimeInMinutes);
                cookie.Secure = secure;
                _page.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                SaveSuccess = false;
                throw new Exception("Cookie Save Failed");
            }
            return SaveSuccess;
        }
    }

    public string GetCookieValue(string cookieName, string valueKey = null)
    {
        if (typeof(string) != cookieName.GetType() || typeof(string) != valueKey.GetType())
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter type mismatch");
        else
        {
            string keyExist = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (Exist(cookieName) == IsExisting)
                {
                    keyExist = (string)_page.Request.Cookies[cookieName][valueKey];
                    return ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyExist)) ? String.Empty : _page.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Values[valueKey]
                        );
                }
                else
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Cookie with the name provided doesnot exist");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool DeleteCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        if (typeof(string) != cookieName.GetType())
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter type mismatch");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (_page.Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null)
                {
                    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                    _page.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                    IsExisting = false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { throw ex; }
        }
    }
}
```

Called this class in my web page as-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CookieHelper cook = new CookieHelper(this.Page);
        if (!cook.Exist("Preferences"))
        {
            cook.CreateCookie("Preferences",2);
            Response.Write("Created");
        }
        else
            Response.Write("Not");

    }
```

Giving me always Created. I added breakpoint and checked in debug and found that compiler always goes to creating section. Please suggest me to create this helper class.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you are missing

`Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);`

in your `CreateCookie` else condition.

Therefore it would look like:

```
HttpCookie cookie=new HttpCookie(cookieName);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiryTimeInMinutes);
cookie.Secure = secure;
CreateSuccess = true;
IsExisting = true;
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

This ensures the cookie is added to the response, so the browser knows the replay it each time it visits.

Here is a [good starting place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287547%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for information on cookies in the web forms environment.

Comment: Is this similar  as _page.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); because doing this in .cs giving me same result

Comment: Assuming `_page` is of type `System.Web.UI.Page` then yes

Comment: I have done as suggested, still getting cookie created everytime.